# Print array values to their own dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph-theory

Here is my data frame:

```
                                             al
0   [[12, 13], [12, 14], [12, 15], [12, 16], [12, ...
1   [[12, 13], [12, 14], [12, 15], [12, 16], [12, ...
2   [[11, 12], [11, 13], [11, 14], [11, 15], [11, ...
3   [[11, 12], [11, 13], [11, 14], [11, 15], [11, ...
4   [[12, 13], [12, 14], [12, 15], [12, 16], [12, ...
...     ...
43234   [5, 7, 4, [3, 8, 9], [1, 8, 10], [7, 9, 10], [...
43235   [5, 4, 6, [2, 7, 8], [1, 9, 10], [3, 7, 8, 9, ...
43236   [6, 4, 5, [2, 7, 8], [3, 6, 7, 8], [1, 5], [4,...
43237   [4, 6, 5, [1, 7, 8], [3, 6, 7, 8], [2, 5], [4,...
```

Each row is a graph, the length of each row is the number of nodes, and each array or singular value (like in row 43234) is the nodes target(s). I want to create a separate df that looks like this:

```
graph_id  src   dst
       0    0    12
       0    0    13
       0    1    12
       0    1    14
       0    2    12
       0    2    15
       0    3    12
.
.
.
   43234    0     5
   43234    1     7
   43234    2     4
   43234    3     3
   43234    3     8
.
.
.
```

I tried multiple versions of this loop:

```
for i in range(len(df['al'])):
    for j in range(len(df['al'][i])):
        for k in range(len(df['al'][i][j])):
            df2['graph_id'] = i
            df2['src'] = j
            df2['dst'] = k
```

to no avail. Let me know if you need any other infomration

Comment: Maybe break the problem down and solve each part individually.  If you can solve it for one row, it will be easy to apply that solution to all rows.  Within, say row 0, if you can solve it for node 0, it will be easy to apply that solution to the other nodes.  Within node 0, if you can solve it for destination 0, ...  Also, list comprehensions and/or dataframe concatenations or appends might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the structure of your dataframe is similar to this. Each cell is a list (works also with array).

```
# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a1': [[np.array([10,11]), np.array([12,13]), np.array([14,15])], 
           [21,22,23, np.array([30,31]), np.array([32,33])]]
})

print(df)
                                 a1
0    [[10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15]]
1  [21, 22, 23, [30, 31], [32, 33]]
```

Then to get the result, you can use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) twice, and create the src column with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) after the first `explode`. The rest in the following code is mostly cosmetic to fit the expected output.

```
res = (
    df
      # create a row per item in the list of each cell
      .explode('a1') 
       # rename the index per your expected output
      .rename_axis('graph_id')
      # create the column src, +1 per row within the same original row number
      .assign(src=lambda x: x.groupby(level='graph_id').cumcount())
      # explode the cells, when array then several row, if scalar, then stay one row
      .explode('a1')
      # to fit expected output names
      .rename(columns={'a1':'dst'})
      # graph_id becomes a column
      .reset_index()
      # reorder the columns per expected output
      [['graph_id', 'src','dst']]
)
print(res)
    graph_id  src dst
0          0    0  10
1          0    0  11
2          0    1  12
3          0    1  13
4          0    2  14
5          0    2  15
6          1    0  21
7          1    1  22
8          1    2  23
9          1    3  30
10         1    3  31
11         1    4  32
12         1    4  33
```

If you are unsure what happens, I suggest you comment all the commands, and uncomment one at the time to see the result of each one of them.